# How to debug a Python program that freezes on one line?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run my code ,it just stay in the line `image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([test_images, test_labels])` without any error prompt. It just stays here and can't move.

Here is my code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from  color_1 import read_and_decode, get_batch, get_test_batch
import color_inference
import cv2
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import color_train
import math

batch_size=128
num_examples = 10000
crop_size=56

def evaluate():
    image_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 56, 56, 3], name='x-input')
    label_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size], name='y-input')

    test_image, test_label = read_and_decode('val.tfrecords')
    test_images, test_labels = get_test_batch(test_image, test_label, batch_size, crop_size)
    y=color_inference.inference(image_holder)

    num_iter = int(math.ceil(num_examples / batch_size))
    true_count = 0
    total_sample_count = num_iter * batch_size

    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(y, label_holder, 1)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        ckpt=tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(color_train.MODEL_SAVE_PATH)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            ckpt_name = os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
            saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(color_train.MODEL_SAVE_PATH, ckpt_name))
            print('Loading success, global_step is %s' % global_step)

            image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([test_images, test_labels])
            predictions = sess.run([top_k_op], feed_dict={image_holder: image_batch,
                                                          label_holder: label_batch})
            true_count += np.sum(predictions)
            print("Count is:%g" % true_count)
            precision = true_count * 1.0 / total_sample_count
            print("After %s training step,the prediction is :%g",global_step,precision)
        else:
            print('No checkpoint file found')
            return

def main(argv=None):
    evaluate()

if __name__=='__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

My last question is similar with this ,but the code is litter different with this, maybe you can get something in last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not starting the queue-runners / initializing the variables properly. I have seen similar behavior with my models when i forgot to to that.
When this is the case you most likely get stuck at the line

```
image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([test_images, test_labels])
```

because the threads that pull data from the tfrecords have not been started.

Before you initialize your session setup an op for initializing the variables and a thread-coordinator:

```
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
```

then at the very start of your session, before pulling any data from the tfrecords you run the op and start the queue runners:

```
sess.run(init_op)
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
# main loop goes here, like training and evaluating
```

Comment: Thank you very much . And can you please help with my another question? The question name is " Fetch argument <tf.Tensor 'batch:0' shape=(128, 56, 56, 3) dtype=float32> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor." in my another question.I need your help! thank you very much